# how to test void method angular Jasmine

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

I have this function, which calls some methods and a service, I would like to know if there is a simple way to mock it and test it please

```
public cutState(i:number) {
 this.loader = true;
 this.dataSource.data[i].state === 'ENABLE' ? 'DISABLE' : 'ENABLE'
 this._cutsServices.setCuts(this.dataSource.data[i]).suscribe(response => {
 this.loader = false;
 this.loadCut()
 swal.fire({
   tittle: `!${this.nameRule} update!`,
   icon: 'success',
   showCancelButton:false,
   confirmButtonText:'exit'
 });
}, error => {
   this.loader = false
   swal.fire({
     tittle:'Error',
     icon: error,
     showCancelButton:false
     confirmButtonText: 'Exit'
    });
  });
}
```

I have tried to mock up the array, but at compilation time it sends this error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state') and all this has happened when wanting to migrate angular 8 -> 9, because those tests previously passed. Besides that sometimes they happen and other times they don't and it confuses me.

component.spec.ts

```
const cuts = [{
 name: 'epale_test',
 state: 'DISABLE'
}]

beforeEach(async()){...}

beforeEach(()=> {
  fixture = TestBed.createCompontent(CutComponent)
  component = fixture.componenteInstance
  component.dataSource.data = cuts
  fixture.detectChanges()
})

it('cut Component', ()=>{
  component.dataSource.data = cuts
  component.dataSource[0].state = 'DISABLE'
  component.cutState(0)
})
```

It also sends me this error: Cannot set properties of undefined (settin 'state')
grateful for your comments